# Как исключить вывод обьекта тип NullShape на экран

Tags: c++, классы, типы

моя функция generate изменяет тип моего обьекта базового класса на любой из 4 предложенных, после вывода типа моего обьекта я проверяю его на равенство с типом обьекта NullShape, но все время получаю что мои обьекты являются членами базового класса First_Name, как сделать чтобы значение типов обьекта сохранялось для дальнейшего вывода и сравнения

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class First_Name
{
private:
char first_name[40];

public:
virtual void vyvod()
{
    cout << "Введите фамилию" << endl;
    cin >> first_name;
    cout << first_name[0] << endl;
}

};

class Last_Name :public First_Name
{
private:
char second_name[40];

public:
void vyvod()
{
    cout << "Введите имя" << endl;
    cin >> second_name;
    cout << second_name[0] << endl;
}


};

class Middle_Name : public Last_Name
{
private:
char middle_name[40];

public:
void vyvod()
{
    cout << "Введите Отчество" << endl;
    cin >> middle_name;
    cout << middle_name[0] << endl;

}


};

class NullShape : public First_Name
{
public:
void vyvod() {};
};



First_Name* generate(First_Name *ob)
{
switch (rand() % 4)
{
case 0: 

{ ob = new First_Name;

    return ob;

}
case 1:

{ ob = new Last_Name;

return ob;

}
case 2:

{ ob = new Middle_Name;

return ob;

}
case 3:

{ ob = new NullShape;

return ob;

}
}
return nullptr;
}



int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
NullShape ob_1;
First_Name ob_2,ob_3,ob_4,ob_5,ob_6,ob_7,ob_8;
cout << typeid(*generate(&ob_2)).name() << endl;
if (typeid(ob_2) == typeid(ob_1))
{
    cout << "Обьект типа NullShape"<<endl;
}
else
    cout << typeid(ob_2).name() << endl;

//cout << typeid(*generate(&ob_2)).name() << endl;
//cout << typeid(*generate(&ob_3)).name() << endl;
//cout << typeid(*generate(&ob_4)).name() << endl;
//cout << typeid(*generate(&ob_5)).name() << endl;
//cout << typeid(*generate(&ob_6)).name() << endl;
//cout << typeid(*generate(&ob_7)).name() << endl;
//cout << typeid(*generate(&ob_8)).name() << endl;
```

}

Comment: *"моя функция generate изменяет тип моего обьекта базового класса"* - нет, эта функция ничего не изменяет. Она создает новые объекты, сохраняя указатель на них в переменной `ob`. Тип объекта изменить нельзя.

Comment: тогда она возвращает другой обьект?

Comment: Она возвращает указатель на новый объект.

Comment: я никогда не встречал virtual int typeid()

Comment: @VTT понял, забыл просто.

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться, передавая в `generate` указатель на `First_Name`?.. И потом - у вас объекты `ob_#` объявлены как объекты точно определенного класса; их тип вы изменить не сможете...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `main` - объекты `FirstName` уже созданы. Вы отправляете их адрес функции `generate`. Эта функция игнорирует аргумент и делает новый объект. Вы игнорируете указатель на новый объект в `main` и память выделенная остаётся мусором. Решается изменением переменных на тип указатель `FirstName *`, `generate(FirstName * & )`. Дальше начальную точку в случайных числах нужно задавать с помощью таймера компа.
Удаление объекта также нужно используя виртуальный деструктор.

Пример рабочий, но у меня консоль в UTF-8. Извиняйте.

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o typeid typeid.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class First_Name
{
private:
wchar_t first_name[40];

public:

virtual void vyvod()
{
    wcout << L"Введите фамилию" << endl;
    wcin >> first_name;
    wcout << first_name[0] << endl;
}
virtual ~ First_Name(){}

};

class Last_Name :public First_Name
{
private:
wchar_t second_name[40];

public:
void vyvod()
{
    wcout << L"Введите имя" << endl;
    wcin >> second_name;
    wcout << second_name[0] << endl;
}
virtual  ~Last_Name(){}

};

class Middle_Name : public Last_Name
{
private:
wchar_t middle_name[40];

public:
void vyvod()
{
    wcout << L"Введите Отчество" << endl;
    wcin >> middle_name;
    wcout << middle_name[0] << endl;

}
virtual  ~Middle_Name(){}
};

class NullShape : public First_Name
{
public:
void vyvod() {};
virtual  ~NullShape(){}
};



First_Name* generate(First_Name * & ob)
{
switch (rand() % 4)
{
case 0: 

{ ob = new First_Name;

    return ob;

}
case 1:

{ ob = new Last_Name;

return ob;

}
case 2:

{ ob = new Middle_Name;

return ob;

}
case 3:

{ ob = new NullShape;

return ob;

}
}
return nullptr;
}



int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
time_t t;
srand((unsigned) time(&t));
NullShape ob_1;
First_Name * ob_2;
generate(ob_2);
wcout << L"typeid(*ob_2).name() = "<<typeid(*ob_2).name() << endl;

if (typeid(*ob_2) == typeid(ob_1))
{
    wcout << L"Обьект типа NullShape"<<endl;
}
else
    wcout <<L"typeid(*ob_2).name() = "<< typeid(*ob_2).name() << endl;
delete ob_2;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: вообше то  NullShape ob_1 совершенно не нужный обьект для данной программы

Answer (score 0):

Во первых ваши обьекты должны создаваться корректно, поэтому они должны быть инициализированы конструктором или инициализаторами при определении. И не важно, что вы можете их инициализировать в каком то методе класса.   Так что во всех классах инициализируйте свой массив как нибудь(хотябы так: `char middle_name[40] = { '0' };`).

Теперь вы хотите узнать на  обьект какого типа указывает возвращаемый функцией указатель, но обьявляете для этого какие то локальные обьекты и хотите в их адрес записать адрес обьекта другого типа. Нет, так не получится. Адрес конкретного обьекта может служить только для чтения. Нужно так:

```
First_Name* pob = 0;
cout << typeid(*generate(pob)).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(*generate(pob)).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(*generate(pob)).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(*generate(pob)).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(*generate(pob)).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(*generate(pob)).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(*generate(pob)).name() << endl;
```

Вообше то функция реализована неправильно, потому что она дает возможность туда передать указатель на любой из типов, и чтобы  он принял адрес своего базового класса, нужно кастить. Лучше просто без аргумента...